# How do i select only the files that starts with either CH or OTC

Tags: regex

How do i select only the files that starts with either CH or OTC

```
import re

#Check if the string starts with "The" and ends with "Spain":

txt = "ho rain in Spain"
x = re.search("^[The|he]", txt)

if x:
  print("YES! We have a match!")
else:
  print("No match")
```

This shows result as YES! We have a match , but i want result as "No match"

Comment: The question, pattern and example data are all different

Comment: `[The|he]` is a character class. Use a group, `(The|he)` or `(?:The|he)`. Or, here, you may just use `T?he`